# Bug: FrontEnd crash with Locator, Arrow and Dynamic

Tags: graphics, bugs, dynamic, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and fixed in Mathematica 11.3**

> [CASE:3731068] It does appear that Locator is not behaving properly and can seemingly crash Mathematica's Front-end, and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided.

---

When I quickly drag the upper-right locator in this dynamic graphic

```
p1 = {0, 0}
p2 = {1, 1}

Dynamic@Graphics[{Arrow[{p1, p2}], Locator[Dynamic[p1]], 
   Locator[Dynamic[p2]]}, PlotRange -> 1]
```

all the way to the left or right boundary, my FrontEnd crashes. Can somebody reproduce this?

This is `$Version` "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"

Comment: reproduced on V10.4, V11.0.1 Win7

Comment: I filed a report.

Comment: If you use the standard bugs header, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info, there is a web app that can track the bug....

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the pointer. Where is the app?